# How to access variable inside nested @classmethod from custom import file in Python?

Tags: python, oop

Let's consider the following code,

**Actual file**

```
[test.py]  
from util.rx import RX

msg = RX.get_msg('Albert!')
print(msg)
```

**Utility class file**

```
[rx.py]  

class RX(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'Hello '    # How to define this var? (self.data or cls.data)

    @classmethod
    def msg(cls, name):
        return self.data + name

    # Shall I use "@staticmethod" in below? If once yes, then how to call the another
    # method inside the same class? (i.e, without 'self' or 'cls')
    @classmethod
    def get_msg(cls, name = None):
        return cls.msg(name)
```

**Expected output:**
Hello Albert!

Any ideas, then please! Thanks.

Comment: Why are your methods `@classmethod`s?

Comment: Heck, why does this class exist at all? This isn't Java; you don't have to stick your helper functions in a class.

Comment: I would like to access the helper methods without creating objects in the main class, (eg. HlprClass.some_util_method())

Comment: You don't need to create any objects. You just need `from rx import msg`, `msg('foo')`.

Comment: Then, how do we implement to use the same method at different utility files in the same way, eg. `from rx11 import *` `from rx22 import *` and same method `def get_msg()`

Comment: By not using `import *`. `import *` is a dangerous, highly discouraged operation. `import rx11` would give you namespaced access to a module-level `get_msg` as `rx11.get_msg`, with no need to abuse classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define class variables *in the class*:

```
class RX(object):
    data = 'Hello '  # here

    @classmethod
    def msg(cls, name):
        return cls.data + name

    @classmethod
    def get_msg(cls, name=None):
        return cls.msg(name)
```

And `classmethods` are typically called on the class, thus the first argument should be assumed to be the class.